# How can I LEFT JOIN two arrays of structs within a single row?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with ["Action Breakdown" data extracted from Facebook's Ads Insights API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns)

Facebook doesn't put the `action` (# of purchases) and the `action_value` ($ amount of purchase) in the same column, so I need to JOIN those on my end, based on the identifier of the action (id# + device type in my case).

If each action were simply its own row, it would of course be trivial to JOIN them with SQL. But in this case, I need to JOIN the two structs *within* each row. What I'm looking to do amounts to a `LEFT JOIN` across two structs, matched on two columns. Ideally I could do this with SQL alone (not PySpark/Scala/etc).

So far I have tried:

- The [SparkSQL `inline` generator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline). This gives me each action on its own row, but since the parent row in the original dataset doesn't have a unique identifier, there isn't a way to JOIN these structs on a per-row basis. Also tried using `inline()` on both columns, but only 1 "generator" function can be used at a time.
- Using [SparkSQL `arrays_zip` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#arrays_zip) to combine them. But this doesn't work because the order isn't always the same and they sometimes don't have the same keys.
- I considered writing a `map` function in PySpark. But it seems map functions only identify columns by index and not name, which seems fragile if the columns should change later on (likely when working with 3rd party APIs).
- I considered writing a [PySpark UDF](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python.html), which seems like the best option, but requires a permission I do not have (`SELECT on anonymous function`). If that's truly the best option, I'll try to push for that permission.

To better illustrate: Each row in my dataset has an `actions` and `action_values` column with data like this.

```js
actions = [
  {
    "action_device": "desktop",
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.123",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "action_device": "desktop", /* Same conversion ID; different device. */
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.321",
    "value": "1"
  },
  {
    "action_device": "iphone", /* Same conversion ID; different device. */
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.321",
    "value": "2"
  }
  {
    "action_device": "iphone", /* has "actions" but not "actions_values" */
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.789",
    "value": "1"
  },
]
action_values = [
  {
    "action_device": "desktop",
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.123",
    "value": "49.99"
  },
  {
    "action_device": "desktop",
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.321",
    "value": "19.99"
  },
  {
    "action_device": "iphone",
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.321",
    "value": "99.99"
  }
]
```

I would like each row to have both datapoints in a single struct, like this:

```js
my_desired_result = [
  {
    "action_device": "desktop",
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.123",
    "count": "1", /* This comes from the "action" struct */
    "value": "49.99" /* This comes from the "action_values" struct */
  },
  {
    "action_device": "desktop",
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.321",
    "count": "1",
    "value": "19.99"
  },
  {
    "action_device": "iphone",
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.321",
    "count": "2",
    "value": "99.99"
  },
  {
    "action_device": "iphone",
    "action_type": "offsite_conversion.custom.789",
    "count": "1",
    "value": null /* NULL because there is no value for conversion#789 AND iphone */
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#transform) and then use [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#filter) to find the first matched item from `action_values` by matching action_device and action_type:

```
df.printSchema()
root
 |-- action_values: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- action_device: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- action_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- actions: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- action_device: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- action_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)

df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_table")

spark.sql("""

  SELECT       
    transform(actions, x -> named_struct(
      'action_device', x.action_device,
      'action_type', x.action_type,
      'count', x.value,
      'value', filter(action_values, y -> y.action_device = x.action_device AND y.action_type = x.action_type)[0].value
    )) as result
  FROM df_table

""").show(truncate=False)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|result                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[desktop, offsite_conversion.custom.123, 1, 49.99], [desktop, offsite_conversion.custom.321, 1, 19.99], [iphone, offsite_conversion.custom.321, 2, 99.99], [iphone, offsite_conversion.custom.789, 1,]]|
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**UPDATE:** in case of the FULL JOIN, you can try the following SQL:

```
spark.sql("""

  SELECT

  concat(
    /* actions left join action_values with potentially multiple matched values */
    flatten(
      transform(actions, x ->
        transform(
          filter(action_values, y -> y.action_device = x.action_device AND y.action_type = x.action_type),
          z -> named_struct(
            'action_device', x.action_device,
            'action_type', x.action_type,
            'count', x.value,
            'value', z.value
          )
        )
      )
    ),
    /* action_values missing from actions */
    transform(
      filter(action_values, x -> !exists(actions, y -> x.action_device = y.action_device AND x.action_type = y.action_type)),
      z -> named_struct(
        'action_device', z.action_device,
        'action_type', z.action_type,
        'count', NULL,
        'value', z.value
      )
    )
  ) as result

  FROM df_table

""").show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: I have no idea how I missed the `transform()` function in the SparkSQL docs. This is [almost] exactly what I was looking for! There's still a potential edge-case where there is an `action_value` that doesn't tie back to an `action` -- or more values than actions (I didn't make this clear in the question). I might be able to solve that a different way, but curious if you have any ideas.

Comment: can you adjust your example to include those cases and also the expected result?

Comment: Question updated. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your help!

Comment: I see a new entry in your update which has action_values not shown in actions. how do you want to handle more than one actions, to put them as their own entries?

Comment: It's worth noting, this solution actually does solve the problem at hand (Facebook conversion data analysis). Logically, it shouldn't be possible to have a conversion value with no action. This edge case hasn't occurred in my 10+ million row dataset spanning multiple years.

Comment: I was going to revert my update, clarify that it's only a LEFT JOIN I need, since I marked your answer as the solution. Turns out you knew my problem better than I did :)

Comment: I added an SQL to handle the full outer join, hope it works for you. good luck :)